# How do we use BigQuery HLL (HyperLogLog) functions in Looker

Tags: google-bigquery, unique, looker, hyperloglog

I have a quick question on how we can use the BigQuery HLL functions in Looker.

For example, there is a BigQuery table with the following structure [Sample BigQuery Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYUbH.png)

1. In looker do I need to define this field respondents_hll as a
   dimension or measure?
2. If I use it as a measure, how can I extract the value of this HLL field at a different grouping level(for example, country only) and use it in dashboards without losing its meaning?
3. If I bring this in as a Dimension, I still want to be able to show the extract of this HLL field at different level? How will looker understand the grouping?

**Best Regards,**
**Sam**

Comment: Ok, on further trial and error, I got this working.

Comment: Explained below.
Basically, we need to define the HLL field as a measure in the view definition. Then use the BigQuery's HLL_COUNT.MERGE functionality in the definition for the column.

Something like this in the View definition:
`measure: unique_respondents {
    group_label: "Unique"
    type: number
    sql: HLL_COUNT.MERGE(${TABLE}.respondents_hll);;
  }`

Looker will automatically (magically ;) ) understand the grouping when you add a dimension and this measure in your explore. Gives you the correct result as the output for that grouping.